# Would you be interested in a "war week" contest?

Tags: discussion

Expanding on [this post](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/community-contest-proposal-new-history-books-what) about potential contest ideas, what do you think about having a "war week"? We did something similar on [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-aristotle-week), where we designate one philosopher each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that philosopher will be eligible to win a prize. It's gotten a positive response so far, and we could easily adapt the model for this site - that is, designate a war each week, and everyone who asks a question about it that week is entered into a drawing to win prizes.

It doesn't necessarily have to be wars either, any significant historical event would probably work. What do you think?

We are taking suggestions for the first war/period/historical event you'd like to focus on, so leave your ideas as answers here!

**[Edit]** Looks like we'll go with WWI for the first week - starting Monday 12/19. I'll make another meta post announcing the official rules then. In the meantime, keep thinking of other ideas for future weekly topics!

Comment: I like this idea. My main question would be pertaining to the prizes. What kind of prizes were awarded and who provided them? Also, how did you go about promoting it to let people know that it was going on?

Comment: @StevenDrennon The prize is any book of the winner's choosing. And, SE takes cares of that. Check philosophy site for how they promoted it (they used a system announcement). We suggest something like a featured post, announcing in chat and we can provide a house ad as well.

Comment: We'll can also promote using social media and such

Comment: Excellent! It sounds good to me!

Comment: Cool -@StevenDrennon do you have any ideas what war/event you'd like to start with?

Comment: I agree with Seth's suggestion for WWI.

Comment: @StevenDrennon any suggestions for next week's topic? We'll probably announce the contest Tuesday morning.

Comment: Why don't we move it up to the next major war and go with WWII?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest for the first week we begin with World War I and the events surrounding it. There is a scarcity of WWI questions and there is general interest (here as well as among curious googlers) about that era.

Comment: I think this would be a great place to start.