# It was World War 1 Week!  (No longer...)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This week, we’re kicking off a “Topic of the Week” series.

How it works: We will designate one topic each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize.

How to enter: Ask a question relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly (this week, use the "ww1" tag). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win a book of your choice (under $50). It can be a book about the topic that week, or anything else you've been wanting to read! Paperback, hardcover, or books for e-readers like Kindle are all fine.

Choosing the topic of the week: For this first week, we decided to go with WW1 (see the discussion [here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140/would-you-be-interested-in-a-war-week-contest)). But for all following weeks we want to take suggestions from you! It can be a war, time period, or any other significant historical event. Leave your suggestion as an answer to this meta post, and the topic that is voted the highest at the end of each round will be the topic of the following week.

Each round will be announced Monday morning at approximately 10 am EST.

**[Edit]**: World War 1 Week is now over. Congratulations to DVK for winning! We don't have a topic picked for the next contest yet, so if you have suggestions, please leave them as answers to this meta post.

Comment: I've tried to sprinkle in a couple of hopefully good questions. Hope this will get the ball rolling. P.S. @Lauren - Your profile is wrong - it doesn't list History.SE as one of your assignments :)

Comment: Awesome! They look like great questions. Hopefully others will see and realize this is going on. 

Also, I've updated my profile! Thanks.

Comment: I've learnt my lesson - lost out on a couple of great grants on SciFi.SE due to rarely reading meta despite being 100% qualified for both :)

Comment: @DVK any ideas for next week's topic? Probably will announce it Monday or Tuesday morning.

Comment: How about Russian history (until 1917). Or Vikings as alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I missed this!  Is there any chance of it happening again?

For myself, I'd love to see more questions that aren't about European or American history - how about China or India week?

Comment: We've stopped doing weekly topic challenges on history for the time being. Unfortunately we weren't seeing a lot of participation. Good suggestions though. If we start it up again we'll keep them in mind.

Comment: Wow. this looks interesting any hope of starting again, @Lauren?

Comment: We won't be doing them again any time soon, I'm working on a few other sites at the moment. Sorry!

Comment: I vote for closing this thread.  It's clearly not WWI week anymore, the contest is over and will not be continued in the foreseeable future, and its confusing everybody.  If we want to do any other contest we can open a new thread.

Comment: @BrotherJack - The edit says the answers to this question are for suggesting the next topic. Seems a reasonable way to do it to me, as long as everyone understands.

Comment: ...oh. And +1 mostly for the India Week idea. That's one area I could really use some brushing up on.

Answer (score 2):

For another special week, I'd suggest Austronesian week.

This would be a week for questions about the history of the Austronesian language area (not nessecarily limited to Austronesian speakers), roughly including Indonesia, the Malay peninsula, New Guinea, Polynesia, New Zeeland, Madagascar, and Easter Island. I know most of New Guinea doesn't speak Austronesian, but I'd include the whole island anyway, just because New Guinea is cool. :-)

[image]

Comment: I think this is a fantastic idea. Such a sparsely populated part of the world, and geographically enormous.

Answer (score 2):

I realized about halfway through composing [this question on the relative values of gold and silver](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/when-was-silver-ever-more-valuable-than-gold) that it actually kind of ties in to the Olympics happening this month.

So how about we make this Olympics month? Anything even remotely tying in to the Olympics (which admittedly could be damn near any question, as countries from all over the world participate) would qualify.

[image]

Comment: Let's open a new thread for future contests. This one is obviously over and will confuse people.

Comment: Not a bad idea. However, Lauren's edit implied any new ones would go as answers here, so that's what I was going with.

Comment: I suppose. Long-term, this won't work though.

Answer (score 1):

This whole thing began and ended before I arrived here, but I suggest beginning it again.

For the next week, I would suggest a pre-ww1 Germany week-- any questions about Germany before the first world war. We have very few questions on this presently (less than five). Most questions about Germany are either about WW1 or WW2. This interesting area of history is lacking here and needs to be worked on.