# Let's ask about Japan

Tags: discussion, challenge

The [top answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1963/690), by score to my call for weekly challenge ideas was:

> I've only seen Japan come up like twice in questions that isn't about invading China/Asia/WW2.
>
> - Meiji Restoration: supporters/opposition to the restoration, role of the emperor and imperial court, the modernisation programs and reactions to them.
> - Sengoku Era: impact of European contact, effect of religions, social/economic structures, shifts in political systems, role of the central government.

Please use the [japan](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan) tag for new questions and consider asking questions about eras other then the [Sino-Japanese Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Sino-Japanese_War) and the [Pacific War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_War). There are currently 78 questions about the Land of the Rising Sun. [47 are not *also* about wwii.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan+-ww2). Let's see if we can increase both totals. Next week, on Sept. 5, I will tally up the results and post my favorite question asked.

Comment: Here we go: [When did Japan and the Three Kingdoms of Korea first met?](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/15111/739)

Answer (score 8):

Since the challenge was started, the following [questions about Japan](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan) have been asked:

- [When did Japan and the Three Kingdoms of Korea first meet?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15111/when-did-japan-and-the-three-kingdoms-of-korea-first-meet)
- [Did Japan have any continental colonies before modern times?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15115/did-japan-have-any-continental-colonies-before-modern-times)
- [What became of the last samurai?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15140/what-became-of-the-last-samurai)
- [Were there any naval engagements during the Mongol invasions of Japan?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15150/were-there-any-naval-engagements-during-the-mongol-invasions-of-japan)
- [Did Perry's Black Ships attack Edo harbour during his expedition to Japan?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/did-perrys-black-ships-attack-edo-harbour-during-his-expedition-to-japan)
- [Was there a Japanese Exchange, à la Columbian Exchange?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15172/was-there-a-japanese-exchange-ala-the-columbian-exchange)

Not only are those 6 questions we probably would not have otherwise had, none of them are specifically about WWII! Well done.

Normally, I'd pick my favorite question. But this week I think it appropriate call out a top participant:

[image: Semaphore]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3517240.png))</sub>

Of the 6 questions, Semaphore asked one and answered 4 in spectacular fashion.