# Let's ask about the Middle East

Tags: discussion, challenge

The [next suggestion on the list](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1965/690) is:

> I would like to see questions about the history of the Middle East region that aren't focused on the past 20 some years, or centered around religion. Basically, pre-20th century Middle East history.

As it happens, I've been listening to [*Bible and Sword: England and Palestine from the Bronze Age to Balfour*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345314271) by Barbara W. Tuchman, so if I get my act together, I'd like to participate too.

Please use the [middle-east](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-east) tag for your questions. At the moment, there are 59 of them. Let's see how many we have next Friday!

Comment: To be fair we actually get rather a lot of these, but they tend to be centered around events or people depicted in either The Bible or The Koran.

Comment: A small quibble: the actual term *middle-east* is a 20th century invention; the region was referred to using different terms before, such as *near-east*, *orient*, or specific ones like *Persia*, *Levant*, *Arabia* and so on. It seems a bit incongruous to tag like this, somewhat like using a USA tag on pre-Colombian North America.

Comment: Another term would be *Asia minor*.

Comment: Asia Minor is being used only for Anatolia. You cannot use it for Egypt, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I did not end up rising to the challenge and neither, it seems, did many of you. We had two new [middle-east](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-east) questions:

- [What property relations existed between peasants and those who took from peasants in early Ottoman rule in Anatolia?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15177/what-property-relations-existed-between-peasants-and-those-who-took-from-peasant)
- [Baldwin IV, the Leper King](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15228/baldwin-iv-the-leper-king)

As [congusbongus mentioned](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/lets-ask-about-the-middle-east?cb=1#comment3319_1970), that's probably the wrong tag anyway. But I don't see any [asia-minor](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asia-minor) questions either. Please let me know if I missed any questions on this general topic.

Comment: Time yet for a new topic?

Comment: @CGCampbell: Yes it is. Overdue even...