# Let's talk about food

Tags: discussion, challenge

The next suggestion on [our list of topics](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/weekly-topic-challenge) is [food](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food). It reminds me of a show I watched a few years ago about the life of typical Romans during the empire. Naturally, I assumed they ate a lot of pasta, but the host pointed out that pasta was brought by Marco Polo from China. But a [quick Wikipedia search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasta#History) suggests that's not at all true. At any rate, this is a fascinating topic and I look forward to seeing what is asked in the coming week.

Comment: OK. Tried my hand at one: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/where-did-southern-fried-chicken-come-from  I hope its not too obscure.

Comment: congusbongus provided this question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/how-much-salt-did-people-in-agricultural-societies-eat

Answer (score 1):

This was a particularly interesting topic and we got 7 fascinating questions:

- [Where did Southern Fried Chicken come from?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/where-did-southern-fried-chicken-come-from)
- [Why did meat and dairy drop out of the working people in Britain's diet during the industrial enclosures period?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15376/why-did-meat-and-dairy-drop-out-of-the-working-people-in-britains-diet-during-t)
- [How did Americans adopt processed and off-site butchered meat for domestic consumption in their food supply?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15377/how-did-americans-adopt-processed-and-off-site-butchered-meat-for-domestic-consu)
- [When was tofu invented? Was it specifically for vegetarian consumption from the beginning?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15378/when-was-tofu-invented-was-it-specifically-for-vegetarian-consumption-from-the)
- [How did Chinese sausages come about?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15426/how-did-chinese-sausages-come-about)
- [Easter Islands: were the Islanders starving when found?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15428/easter-islands-were-the-islanders-starving-when-found)
- [How much salt did people in agricultural societies eat?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/how-much-salt-did-people-in-agricultural-societies-eat)

I really enjoyed [Semaphore's tofu answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/15383/690), but there is plenty of good history represented here. If I had one suggestion, it would be to make sure that answers are backed up with primary and secondary sources when possible.