# Let's ask about religion during the genesis of the US

Tags: discussion, challenge

[Mark C. Wallace suggested](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1961/690):

> Religious diversity in the US from 1770 to 1790. How did the colonies constrain or promote religious diversity as they shifted away from a state controlled church? What were the distribution of religions in the post revolutionary period, which flourished and why? Which diminished and why?

There's no easy tag for this topic, so I propose the combination of [american-revolution](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-revolution) and [religion](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion). It's not a perfect fit, so when the challenge is over we may need to retag some questions. For reference, there are currently [no questions with that combination](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-revolution+religion). Since this is a very narrow topic, I don't expect this challenge to generate as many questions as [earlier challenges](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge).

Comment: How about 1600 to 1750?  Religion during the early colonial period is a topic I've been researching lately.

Comment: Here's [a question](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/what-are-the-evidences-for-muslim-soldiers-fighting-in-the-continental-army). @Joe I agree, perhaps we could count [tag:colonial-america] too; it'd make this topic a bit less narrow as well.

Comment: @Joe: Go for it! (Just be sure to link the questions here so that I can track them.)

Comment: Isn't it past time for a new topic?